# Having trouble extracting a common interface

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

I would like to create a calculator application that can switch between different number bases.  As far as entering digits is concerned, I was thinking the following would be a flexible api:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    string Enter(INumberElement element);
}

public class BaseTenCalculator : ICalculator
{
    public string Enter(INumberElement element)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class BaseTwoCalculator : ICalculator
{
    public string Enter(INumberElement element)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that for the BaseTenCalculator, I would like a method

```
Enter(BaseTenNumberElement element)
```

and for a BaseTwoCalculator, I would like a method

```
Enter(BaseTwoNumberElement element)
```

to make sure only valid digits for that number base get entered.  However, the only way I can think of enforcing this constraint is downcasting the 'element' argument in the two different implementations, and throwing an exception if INumberElement is not of the correct type.  I feel like this is 'wrong', and I'm missing something.  Is there another way? Is it even possible to create a common interface for two different number base calculators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public interface ICalculator<in T> where T : INumberElement
    {
        string Enter(T element);
    }

    public class BaseTenCalculator : ICalculator<BaseTenNumberElement> 
    {
        public string Enter(BaseTenNumberElement element)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class BaseTwoCalculator : ICalculator<BaseTwoNumberElement>
    {
        public string Enter(BaseTwoNumberElement element)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a newby when it comes to generics.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking of the problem incorrectly. A number is a number regardless of base. Base is only a visible representation of the number. A good example to work from might be BigInteger. It has a constructor:  BigInteger(String val, int radix), and a function: toString(int radix). All the work of representing the number is done the same. The only thing that differs is parsing from a string representation into the number, and then getting back out into a number format in a particular base.

You could create a multi-base calculator by using BigInteger or BigDecimal underneath and just using a base selection to set the radix value to parse or print the number(s). You'd also want to limit the input buttons (assuming you're using buttons), but that's really just a counting problem.

Comment: Good points.  I would still like to ensure that, if the user is entering digits on the 'base-ten' setting, that only 0-9. are allowed.  Plus, digits on a calculator get entered one by one, and then 'commited' when an operation or the equals button is pressed.  I could use BigDecimal behind the scenes, but I still need a way to constrain valid input.

Comment: Model-view separation? Your views (plus a controller if you want) will handle the validation of input and formatting of output.